# How to implement a TOC if I'm using html2pdf to convert HTML to PDF?

Tags: itext7, tableofcontents

I'm using the following method to convert html to PDF.

- **HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlCode,servletOutputStream);**

but here I don't have the possibility of handle the Document object to create the TOC according to [this example](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/toc-first-page)

Now if I use

- **Document document=HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(.....)**

  Will it update the document created if I work with that document object?

Comment: Did you read about setting the `ConverterProperties` in the [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml)? Creating a TOC is just a matter of defining an `OutlineHandler'. Can you tell us why the result doesn't look like you expect when you follow the bookmarks example from the PDF to HTML tutorial?

Comment: Sure @BrunoLowagie. I want to have the table of content in the document like the first page of the document. I meant as part of the design of the document.  But like I'm using the html2pdf to convert HTML to PDF, I'm not sure it is possible to update the document once it was created by **convertToDocument** function. Becuase I will need to read all the html again to add the table of content to **document** object.

Comment: Once you have the outlines, you can easily read the outline tree, and use that information to create a real TOC on real pages, hence that's the way to go. As long as you don't close the document, you can add more content. I'm pretty sure you can reorder the pages so that they are in front of the document if necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much @BrunoLowagie. It works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks, if you could copy/paste some of your code (or my comment) into an answer, your answer can be up-voted.